# Is there a WinAPI native function to escape HTML?

Tags: windows, winapi, escaping, html-escape-characters

Is there a native WinAPI to call to escape a string for HTML/XML into `&lt;` `&gt;` etc?

Comment: Do you want entities? > to &gt; et al

Comment: Yes, sorry, seems SO parsed & gt ;

Comment: You could do it manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665231/most-efficient-way-to-escape-xml-html-in-c-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows API does not provide any such simple function, to the very best of my knowledge. That sort of functionality is typically provided by libraries.

Normally you will be using an HTML or XML library to generate your HTML or XML. That's almost always a better strategy than trying to assemble it yourself. And those libraries will do the necessary escaping for you.

For example, a commonly used library to work with XML on Windows is [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763742.aspx). You can use that library to parse and emit XML and it will take care of escaping for you.